# Random binary distribuition

Tags: r, random, binary

I would like to generate a random binary combination (row order) in my dataframe `df`:

```
bin
 2
 2
 2
 2
 3
 2
 3
 2
```

In this example I intend to generate 6 times `0` (the same number of `2`) and two times `1` (the same number of `3`). I expect something like that:

```
bin 
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
 1
 0
 0
```

Any ideas? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So given a vector `bin`

```
bin<-c(2,2,2,2,3,2,3,2)
```

You would like to create a new vector that contains the same number of 0's as the number of 2's in `bin`, and the same number of 1's as the number of 3's in `bin`. Assuming that's correct, then

```
sample(rep(0:1, table(bin)))
```

Should do the trick. Here are the results of running that command several times:

```
# 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
# 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
# 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
# 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0
```